# Send push notification directly from nodejs backend to react-native/expo App

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am working on a mobile app using react native/expo. Now I need to perform the task of sending notifications. I'm thinking of using a NodeJS backend (this one is connected to a MongoDB database to store the tokens) to send notifications to all users. I have found that you can use Firebase or also the expo push notification tool. But those are external services. Does anyone know of a way to send notifications directly from your own server made in nodeJS (without the need to use firebase).

I appreciate your responses.

Comment: I have never used react-native but does using socketio for features like live notificationa work for you ?

Comment: Thanks @Halil , Interesting point. I am going to investigate if it is possible to connect socketio with react native, because I know socketio is usefull for webs.